# Problems with behavior of ExpandableListView and ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview

So, I created a custom ExpandableListAdapter because I wanted an expandable list capable of having multiple children, essentially a two-tiered list. It's been working perfectly fine, as long as it was the first and only View in the Activity. However, I recently added some other Views (a set of TextViews) to the LinearLayout it's in, and all of a sudden it's stopped displaying at all, without giving any errors.

First, I'm wondering if it is, for some reason, required to be the first/only view in the Activity, and if so, if there's any way of getting around that. Code is below.

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.finalcalculation_list_view);
final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
        this, groupList, totalCollection);
expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" > 

        <!-- Here are some TextViews -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/finalcalculation_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/finalcalculation_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </ExpandableListView>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how it was originally, when it was last working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/finalcalculation_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the unfortunately large code-dump of my ExpandableListAdapter.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    private Map<String, List<String>> collections;
    private List<String> groups;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> groups,
            Map<String, List<String>> collections) {
        this.context = context;
        this.collections = collections;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return collections.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finalcalculation_child_item, null);
        }

        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.finalcalculation_child_item_textview);

        item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                List<String> child = 
                                    collections.get(groups.get(groupPosition));
                                child.remove(childPosition);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        item.setText(laptop);
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return collections.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String itemName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater groupInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = groupInflater.inflate(R.layout.finalcalculation_group_item, null);
        }
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.finalcalculation_group_item_textview);
        item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        item.setText(itemName);
        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the Inflators for both getChildView and getGroupView from

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finalcalculation_child_item, null);
```

to both

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finalcalculation_child_item, parent, false); //AND
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finalcalculation_child_item, parent, true); //AND
```

But it either doesn't work, or throws an error.

All help and input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `layout_height` of the nested `LinearLayout` is set to `match_parent`, which causes the nested `LinearLayout` to be the same height of the parent `LinearLayout` and hides the `ScrollView`. It should be something like `wrap_content` or a fixed size. Also, you don't need a `ScrollView`.

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" > 

        <!-- Here are some TextViews -->

    </LinearLayout>

   <ExpandableListView
       android:id="@+id/finalcalculation_list_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Beautiful - this is perfect. You were absolutely right about the LinearLayout, that was an oversight on my part. However, just changing that still left the ExpandableListView only showing the first group item, and none of the children would expand; removing the ScrollView, however, made it revert to its proper behavior, showing all groups and children, and expanding properly. I had assumed I needed a ScrollView, but it seems like the ExpandableListView deals with scrolling on its own. Perfect answer. Thank you!